# php fast recursive directory filter

Tags: php, performance, optimization, directory, spl

I have to search for xml-files recursively in a large directory and have to test if they contain a specific tag '< run >'. At the moment I use a RecursiveDirectoryIterator with a RecursiveFilterIterator, because I thought the new PHP SPL would be the fastest solution, but it isn't (it's not possible to calculate a result within 30s) - what would be the fastest way? a recursive glob? I would not have enough time to test/profile all possible ways to get all xml files and test if they contain this tag.

filter implementation:

```
class MyRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator {

public function accept() {

    if ($this->current()->isDir())
        return true;

    if (Utils::endsWith($this->current(), "xml")){

        $content = file_get_contents($this->current());

        if(strpos($content, "<run>") !== false)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    return false;

}

}
```

catch all arrays:

```
[..]
$result = array();

    try  {

        $dirItr    = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root);
        $filterItr = new MyRecursiveFilterIterator($dirItr);
        $itr       = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filterItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);


        foreach ($itr as $filePath => $fileInfo) {
            if($fileInfo->isDir())
                continue;

            array_push($result, $filePath);

        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e);
    }
[..]
```

any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

the *hard core* linux version needs only about 1 or 2 seconds!! wouldn't it possible to achieve similary results in php?!

```
$output = `find $root -type f -iname "*.xml" | xargs grep "<run>" --files-with-matches`;
$output = explode("\n", $output);
```

**EDIT 2:**
Found a even faster bash version:

```
 find path/to/files \( -name ".*" -prune -or \( -type f -and -name "*.xml" \) \) -and -not -name ".*" -exec grep -lsm 10 "^<" {} \+
```

Comment: Are you expecting <run> to be towards the beginning of the file? If so, you might want to avoid loading the entire file to check for it, but rather favour a line-by-line approach.

Comment: ok, I changed file_get_contents to open.. fgets.. and read only 10 lines, but it changed next to nothing...

Comment: Interesting. How many xml files are we dealing with here, and what average size are they? (roughly)

Comment: The test-directory has about 60000 files/subdirs, but only 2 files match the pattern. I test it on a virtual machine. How can I achieve better results? (the bash version is nearly perfect (~1.3s) but the php-script takes more than 30...

Comment: Maybe I'm being too pragmatic, but if speed is what you're after, why not just use the bash version in PHP and go from there? Building recursive iterators and doing everything OO is nice, but it takes time.

Comment: At the moment I have to use the bash version, because php takes far to long, but this program should be at least a little bit platform independent and bash isn't.

Comment: Perhaps you could run it once, and then catalog the locations of the .xml files that have <run> in them? Or do they have the potential to change? You could also track which files have been modified instead of opening them, which might be faster.

Comment: they can change, so this wouldn't be easy. Furthermore the script will run on several workstations - if I track only the changes, I would have to create an index, but if there are many folders php wouldn't cover the charge..